# Am I Properly Normalizing this Table

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization, third-normal-form

The following problem comes from: https://cs.senecac.on.ca/~dbs201/pages/Normalization_Practice.htm (Exercise 3)

The unnormalized table appears like this:

[image: UNF]

To comply with First Normal Form, all repeating groups must be dealt with. In this case, multiple products could appear on a single order, so it must be given its own entity and related back to the original table:

[image: 1NF/2NF]

These tables are also in Second Normal Form, because in all of the tables, each non-key attribute is dependent on the primary key in it's table.

Finally, to bring it to Third Normal Form, Customer must be given its own entity and related back to the original Order entity:

[image]

Have I properly normalized the original table into Third Normal Form? If not, please provide feedback explaining what I've done wrong.

Comment: Hi. Your comments about normalization are not consistent with understanding it. Normalization does not involve entities; it involves FDs, which you don't mention. Please give your textbook & show how you followed it. Read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what can't be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Comment: Put the problem statement text in your question, not in a link. There is no standard notion of an "unnormalized table" for a design & [there is no standard definition for "1NF"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097) so tell us your textbook and/or exactly what those mean for this assignment. And you don't mention FDs so you seem to have no idea what you are doing so an answer would have to rewrite your textbook & do your work for you--that's an off-topic question. Also we can't critique what you did because giving a few unjustified milestones doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 1):

Store some Customer's Primary details in **Order Table** which are available on Bill, because once customer details is changed then Bill is differ then original.

Same for Product, Store Product price in Product_Order table, because once Product price changed Bill will change.